# android: BroadcastReceiver RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETE does not work

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I want to create an Android application which performs some action periodically (every minute) in the background. The application shall have no user interface, therefore there will be no Action-Class. It shall start automatially after boot.

I have coded my Application as shown below, but it just does not start after boot? Can anyone help?

I am using a Samsung Tablet GT-P5200 with Android 4.4.2

Many thanks for your help in advance.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.somecompany.justoneservice" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**BootReceiver.java**

```
package com.somecompany.justoneservice;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.Log;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public BootReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TAG", "BOOT");
        long interval = DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS * 1;
        long firstStart = System.currentTimeMillis() + interval;
        Intent mainServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        PendingIntent mainServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, mainServiceIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, firstStart, interval, mainServicePendingIntent);

    }
}
```

**MySevice.java**

```
package com.somecompany.justoneservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("TAG", "Service created.");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("TAG", "Service started. (" + startId + ")");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.d("TAG", "Service started.");
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The application shall have no user interface, therefore there will be no Action-Class.

Newly-installed apps' manifest-registered receivers are disabled until something uses an explicit `Intent` to start one of your components. Usually, this is the user tapping on the icon for one of your activities in a home screen's launcher. And usually that is not a problem, because all apps need an activity, to allow the user to configure the behavior of the app, get help, read the license agreement terms, etc.

In some scenarios, something other than a home screen launcher icon can start up one of your components with an explicit `Intent`. For example, if you are a plugin to some other app, that other app might detect your installation and start up one of your components.

But, if nothing will start one of your components with an explicit `Intent`, then your `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver will never get control, even after a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That reflects exactly what I have experienced. when I add any kind of Activity, the App starts perfectly well after even after re-boot. Thanks again.